# Is there any missing value on my x-ray images when i do reshape and reduce the size?

Tags: python

I'm doing classification on x-ray images with deep learning models(pretrained models) and, I reshape the size of images to (100,100,3) to make it faster in training

Is there any missing value here?
thanks in advance to all...

Comment: What shape are your original images? Why reshape a 2D image to 3D?

Comment: It's still 2D just reduce the size and I confirm if there is any missing value or wrong in my way?  the original shape was different because I mixed more than one dataset with different images size, also I used pre-trained models (transfer learning)

Comment: How is (100, 100, 3) still 2D?

Comment: 3 it mean here RGP

Comment: also because I use a pre-trained model and they only accept 3D images as an input so I should make it like this

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.